# convert output from dictionary to list with bfs and dfs networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am currently using networkx library for Python with BFS and DFS. I need to get a tree and then explore it to get a path from a start node to an end node.

For the BFS part I am using `bfs_successors`and it returns an iterator of successors in breadth-first-search from source.

For the DFS part I am using: `dfs_successors` and it returns a dictionary of successors in depth-first-search from source.

I need to get a list of nodes from source to end from both the algorithms. Each node is (x, y) and is a cell in a grid.

Do you have any advice about how to do it? Can you help me please?

MWE:

```
DFS = nx.bfs_successors(mazePRIM,start)
print(dict(BFS))

DFS = nx.dfs_successors(mazePRIM, start)
print(DFS)
```

and I get this:

```
{(0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 2)], (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 2): [(0, 3)]}

{(0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 2)], (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 2): [(0, 3)]}
```

But I need an output like this:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

which is the list of nodes from start to end.

Comment: What do you mean by extrapolating a list of nodes from both algorithms? Can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: hi! I mean get the tree and then find a path from a start node to an end node... I added the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you're not really interested in finding all successors encourtered with `nx.bfs_successors`, since you only need the path between a source and a target nodes.

For that you can either find the [shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) (in the case there are multiple):

```
nx.shortest_path(G, source, target)
```

Or find all simple paths between them:

```
nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, target)
```

Which returns a generator with all simple paths between both nodes.

Comment: But why is that? From your question, I understand that you're only interested in the path between those nodes @hello

Comment: I want to use both and compare their speed to see which one is faster

Comment: My code has lots of lines and I am trying to see which algorithm does the job faster and then print a visual output. I tried Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford, but I would like to see what happens with these ones. This output dict thing is the only part I can't fix...

Comment: But you're not really addressing my question... @hello Why find all successors using  `dfs_successors`, if you're only interested in the path between two nodes?

Comment: Oh ops... I thought it was the right one for doing it

Comment: No... Please take your time to read the answer, and try out the suggested methods @hello IIUC they are what you need

Comment: by seeing they had the same output format (dict), I figured out it would have been easier to get the result... like write a single one function to convert both

Comment: ```nx.shortest_path(G, source, target)``` uses Dijkstra or bellman-ford... I can't use it to get bfs or dfs. Do you know what does ```nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, target)``` use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216073/discussion-between-hellomynameisa-and-yatu).