# find path and convert from dictionary to list

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am using networkx library for Python with BFS and DFS. I need to get a tree and then explore it to get a path from a start node to an end node.

For the BFS part I am using `bfs_successors`and it returns an iterator of successors in breadth-first-search from source.

For the DFS part I am using: `dfs_successors` and it returns a dictionary of successors in depth-first-search from source.

I need to get a list of nodes from source to end from both the algorithms. Each node is (x, y) and is a cell in a grid.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
BFS = nx.bfs_successors(mazePRIM, start)
print(dict(BFS))

DFS = nx.dfs_successors(mazePRIM, start)
print(DFS)
```

and I get this:

```
{(0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 2)], (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 2): [(0, 3)]}

{(0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 2)], (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 2): [(0, 3)]}
```

but I need an output like this:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

which is the list of nodes from start to end.

Do you have any advice about how to do it? Can you help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert output from dictionary to list with bfs and dfs networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412222/convert-output-from-dictionary-to-list-with-bfs-and-dfs-networkx)

Comment: It looks like you are asking the same question here as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412222. `bfs_successors` or `dfs_successors` does not give you the path from `start` to `end` by itself. You can use `shortest_path` or `all_simple_paths` for that.

Comment: Hi @rkersh! Yes, I did, but then I found out the answer was not good for what I needed. I tried to change the post and to cancel it, but I couldn't, so I wrote a new one (this) and got the answer I needed

Comment: The answers below do **not** give you what you asked for in your question. Instead, they give every node that can be reached from `start` using either breadth-first search or depth-first search.

Comment: Well, it helped a lot in completing my code...

Comment: So, what do you suggest? I'm sorry, I don't understand what you think I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and imply add `.keys()` to the end of your dictionaries:

```
DFS = nx.bfs_successors(mazePRIM,start)
print([n for n in dict(BFS).keys()])

DFS = nx.dfs_successors(mazePRIM, start)
print([n for n in DFS.keys()])
```

You can read more about dictionary keys here:

[How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you also know how can I get the path between two elements in a dictionary?

Comment: Change `.keys()` to `.values()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert the dictionary keys directly to a list:

```
DFS = nx.bfs_successors(mazePRIM,start)
print(list(dict(BFS).keys()))

DFS = nx.dfs_successors(mazePRIM, start)
print(list(dict(DFS).keys()))
```